# How to create scheduler for manually refresh Materialized View if the MV get need_compile stallness status

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, materialized-view, jobs

I've a problem to Automatically Refresh Materialized View, if the stallness condition is `NEED_COMPILE / STALE / UNUSABLE OR NOT FRESH`.

I've MV with this PL/SQL :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "some_schema"."MV_TEST_BRO" ("some_field", "some_field", "some_field")
ORGANIZATION HEAP PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "some_tablespace" 
BUILD IMMEDIATE
USING INDEX 
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

btw, my MV is too complex to put it here so I made it simple in here.
After I got an update in table master I test it with below query to get status stallness of my MV.

```
SELECT MVIEW_NAME, STALENESS, LAST_REFRESH_TYPE, COMPILE_STATE FROM USER_MVIEWS ORDER BY MVIEW_NAME;
```

And, I create PL/SQL to refresh that MV like this :

```
BEGIN
DBMS_REFRESH.make(
    name                 => 'some_schema.MINUTE_REFRESH',
    list                 => '',
    next_date            => SYSDATE,
    interval             => '/*1:Mins*/ SYSDATE + 1/(60*24)',
    implicit_destroy     => FALSE,
    lax                  => FALSE,
    job                  => 0,
    rollback_seg         => NULL,
    push_deferred_rpc    => TRUE,
    refresh_after_errors => TRUE,
    purge_option         => NULL,
    parallelism          => 4,
    heap_size            => NULL);
END;

BEGIN
DBMS_REFRESH.add(
    name => 'some_schema.MINUTE_REFRESH',
    list => 'some_schema.MV_TEST_BRO',
    lax  => TRUE);
END;
```

But the interval of that dbms_refresh is not working at all. So I created some scheduler to do the job, this is my PL/SQL :

```
BEGIN
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name => '"some_schema"."REFRESH_MV"',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'begin
       DBMS_REFRESH.REFRESH(name => ''some_schema.MINUTE_REFRESH'');
    end;',
    schedule_name => '"some_schema"."EJS_MV_REFRESH"',
    job_class => '"DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"',
    comments => 'Scheduler untuk merefresh MV pada schema some_schema',
    auto_drop => FALSE,
    enabled => FALSE);
    sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute( name => '"some_schema"."REFRESH_MV"', attribute => 'raise_events', value => dbms_scheduler.job_failed);
    sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute( name => '"some_schema"."REFRESH_MV"', attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_FAILED_RUNS);
    sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute( name => '"some_schema"."REFRESH_MV"', attribute => 'restartable', value => TRUE);
    sys.dbms_scheduler.enable( '"some_schema"."REFRESH_MV"' );
END;
```

So far this solve my problem to automatically refresh MV every 1 minute. But it's not effective at all. **So, My Problem is :**

How to make this `job_action` to execute `DBMS_REFRESH.REFRESH(name => ''some_schema.MINUTE_REFRESH'');` every 1 minute if the status of `stallness is not FRESH` ?

I don't know much about how to use pointer or whatever the name to get the result of query to check `SELECT MVIEW_NAME, STALENESS, LAST_REFRESH_TYPE, COMPILE_STATE FROM USER_MVIEWS ORDER BY MVIEW_NAME;` and use this status to trigger the refresh, it's just like `IF-THEN` condition.

Please help me, if you know how to get that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm successfully able to create a scheduler for my MV to refresh every minutes if the status stallness is not `FRESH`. Here's my solutions :

I created a schedules to be used in my scheduler:

```
BEGIN
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_schedule(
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY',
    start_date => to_timestamp_tz('2015-06-09 01:41:55 Asia/Jakarta', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR'),
    comments => 'Interval refresh 1 menit',
    schedule_name => '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"');
END;
```

After that I create DBMS_SCHEDULER to create a job like this :

```
BEGIN
sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(
job_name => '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action => 'DECLARE
    mv_name USER_MVIEWS.MVIEW_NAME%type;
    mv_status USER_MVIEWS.STALENESS%type;
    mv_last USER_MVIEWS.LAST_REFRESH_TYPE%type;
    mv_state USER_MVIEWS.COMPILE_STATE%type;

    CURSOR check_mv
    IS SELECT MVIEW_NAME, STALENESS, LAST_REFRESH_TYPE, COMPILE_STATE FROM USER_MVIEWS WHERE MVIEW_NAME = ''MV_TEST_BRO'' ORDER BY MVIEW_NAME;

    BEGIN
        OPEN check_mv;

        LOOP
            FETCH check_mv INTO mv_name, mv_status, mv_last, mv_state;
            IF mv_status != ''FRESH'' THEN
                DBMS_REFRESH.REFRESH(name => ''SOME_SCHEMA.MINUTE_REFRESH'');
            ELSE
                EXIT;
            END IF;
            EXIT WHEN check_mv%NOTFOUND;

        END LOOP;

    CLOSE check_mv;
END;',
schedule_name => '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"',
job_class => '"DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"',
comments => 'Refresh MV every 1 Minutes',
auto_drop => FALSE,
enabled => FALSE);
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute( name => '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"', attribute => 'raise_events', value => dbms_scheduler.job_failed);
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute( name => '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"', attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_FAILED_RUNS);
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute( name => '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"', attribute => 'restartable', value => TRUE);
sys.dbms_scheduler.enable( '"SOME_SCHEMA"."REFRESH_MV"' );
END;
```

In the job action, I checked stallness status for specified MV like `MV_TEST_BRO` but you can check the status for every MV you had. And I activated some attribut to raise event if the job failed, logging level, and restartable.

This job was running for a week now and no problem at all. My MV always `FRESH` every time. May be this post will help another who face the same problem like me. :D